# Flink -- RocksDb returns Null, even updated previously

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

I am using RocksDb for state operation in my flink application.

Please take a look this code:

```java
public class Process extends KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, Record, Result>{
    private transient ValueState<Integer> state;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters)
    {
        StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
                .newBuilder(Time.seconds(30))
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.ReturnExpiredIfNotCleanedUp)
                .cleanupInBackground()
                .build();

        ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                "state",
                TypeInformation.of(Integer.class));

        stateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(stateDescriptor);
    }


    @Override
    public void processElement(Record value, Context ctx, Collector<Result> out) throws Exception
    {
        updateStates(value);

        Integer stateValue = state.value();

        logger.info("processElement -- subTaskName: {}, stateValue: {} , ", getRuntimeContext().getTaskNameWithSubtasks() ,stateValue);

        if (stateValue % 2 == 0)
        {
            out.collect(..)
        }
    }


    private void updateStates(Record value) throws Exception
    {

        if (state.value() == null)
        {
            state.update(1);
        }

        Integer stateValue = state.value();
        
        logger.info("updateStates -- subTaskName: {}, stateValue: {} ", getRuntimeContext().getTaskNameWithSubtasks() ,stateValue);
        
        if (something in record true)
        {
            stateValue ++;
            state.update(stateValue);
        }
    }
}
```

In this process function, I am getting `NullPointerException`, because `stateValue` in the process function is null.

And also some logs inside the `updateState()` :

```
2020-12-04 ... INFO  ...  - updateStates -- subTaskName: Process (9/40), stateValue: null
```

Why I am getting Null values from state, even I updated the state previously.

Are rocksdb `update()`and `value()` operations done by async way?

According to the @DavidAnderson request, I am adding the code that uses the KeyedProcessFunction:

```java
public class Record{
    private String customerName; 
    
    // getters and setter for customerName and other fields
}

private DataStream<Result> applyProcess(DataStream<Record> otherStream)
    {
        return otherStream
                .filter(record -> filter if record.method() returns true,-there is no exception in here- )
                .name("filtered")
                .keyBy('customerName')
                .process(new Process())
                .name("ProcessFunction");
 }
```

**UPDATE**: That's seems silly but, application works when I have updated the code like this one: (I just removed the updateStates method and put into the processElement function)

```java
@Override
    public void processElement(Record value, Context ctx, Collector<Result> out) throws Exception
    {
       /* 
        This case is not working...
        if (state.value() == null) {
            stateValue = 1;
        }
        */

         Integer stateValue = state.value();

        if (stateValue == null){
            stateValue = 1;
        }
        

        if (something in record true)
        {
            stateValue ++;
            state.update(stateValue);
        }

        if (stateValue % 2 == 0)
        {
            out.collect(..)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that uses this KeyedProcessFunction? I'm specifically interested in the keyBy, since the key are Tuples -- what are the types used in the fields of the Tuple? If they aren't valid key types, that might explain this behavior.

Comment: This form of keyBy that uses reflection has been deprecated. I don't think this explains what's going on, but I recommend you update the keyBy to something more like `keyBy(record -> record.getCustomerName())`, and then update the key type from Tuple to String in `Process`.

Comment: Anderson thank you for your answer, I did just something different (see my question, i updated), however I do not know the reason :)

Comment: @monstereo I am currently experiencing the same issue on Flink 1.15.2 (running on Kinesis Data Analytics). I wanted to double check: was it really interacting with state in a helper method that was the issue?

Comment: @r_g_s_ Well I can say that run the state.update() method only once.(Get the stateValue in the beginning of the process function and update it end of the process function) Otherwise you may encounter the same issue. (But I don't know the exact reason)